# wordpress count widgets

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

Hi I am trying to figure out as to how can we get the count of widgets published in a given sidebar position.

For example I have a sidebar called UTILITY which is a horizontal sidebar. I want the width of these widget positions to adjust equally according to the number of widgets published in it.

I want to know that on a given page how many widgets are published in this sidebar so that I can assign a width class according to it.

Comment: Does it have to happen on the server side or could you also count the widgets and add the class names with Javascript?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
wp_get_sidebars_widgets()
```

Will give you an array of the sidebars and the widgets they have, just count the array for the appropriate sidebar..

**For example:**

```
$the_sidebars = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();
echo count( $the_sidebars['my-sidebar-id'] );
```

The ID is the one you declare when you register the sidebar(so check your sidebar registration code).

You could also wrap this into a function.

```
function count_sidebar_widgets( $sidebar_id, $echo = true ) {
    $the_sidebars = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();
    if( !isset( $the_sidebars[$sidebar_id] ) )
        return __( 'Invalid sidebar ID' );
    if( $echo )
        echo count( $the_sidebars[$sidebar_id] );
    else
        return count( $the_sidebars[$sidebar_id] );
}
```

Then call it when you need to get the count, using the sidebar ID..

```
count_sidebar_widgets( 'some-sidebar-id' );
```

Or store in variable for other usage..

```
$my_var = count_sidebar_widgets( 'some-sidebar-id', false );
```

Hope that helps..

Comment: @Vikram - You're welcome... for future WordPress based questions, please consider posting to WPSE: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: sure will do as advised. Sorry for this. Actually I am new to Stackoverflow and yet to explore more.

Comment: I'm pretty new myself, no worries, it was only a suggestion(because i frequent there).. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you are building the sidebar, there should be a list containing the sidebar contents; you are iterating over it to add those items to the generated page.  Just use the `count()` function on this list to find the number of items you're displaying.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `global $sidebars_widgets` variable that is an array in the format `sidebar_id => [...widget_ids]`. You can find the number of widgets by using:

```
$numWidgets = count($sidebar_widgets['my-sidebar-id']);
```