# Check if widget is assigned to a specific widget area?

Tags: wordpress

I've registered two sidebars (widget areas), 'big' and 'small'.

I've created a widget that displays a page's title, thumbnail and excerpt.

I want the widget to display a big thumbnail if the widget is assigned to sidebar 'big' and I want it to display a small thumbnail if it's assigned to sidebar 'small'.

e.g.

```
If (widget_assigned() == 'big-sidebar') {
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'big-thumbnail')
}
else {
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'small-thumbnail')
};
```

Is there a Wordpress tag like `widget_assigned()` I can use to achieve this?

Comment: [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441165/wordpress-count-widgets) touches on a solution to your problem. Though, you could also just target what you need with CSS rather than using PHP to determine which sidebar the widget resides in.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar thing by modifying the 'Widget Context' plugin.