# Count number of times a widget is being set on all sidebars in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have Widget X loaded in three different sidebars in the widgets area of Wordpress.

Is there any way I can count the number of times this widget has been loaded in all of the sidebars currently visible?

In my case, after checking I should get "3".
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do what you want using the answer in this post:
[wordpress count widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441165/wordpress-count-widgets) and by counting the widget in multiple sidebars instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery.

```
$(".sidebar").length;
```